# VBA Cannot get the Option via select drop down to work

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to set the value for a drop down box and it shows a blank which is not even an option.

Here is the HTML snip-it: (NOTE: internal website so I cant give URL or too much)

```
<select id="entNo" name="entNo" style="width:75px">
  <option selected="selected" value="All">All</option>
  <option value="650101">650101</option>
  <option value="66">66</option>
```

Here is the function for it.

```
    function requestEntities()
  {
      var ele = document.getElementById('entNo');
      if (ele) {
          ele.options.length = 0;
          ele.options[0] = new Option('All');
          ele.disabled = true;
          ele = document.getElementById('divNo');
          if (ele) {
              var i = ele.selectedIndex;
              var div = ele.options[i].value;
              sendHttpRequest('http://example.com/cgi-bin/wspd_cgi.sh/WService=wslive//wpr/entityList.r?div=' + div);
          }
      }
  }
```

The vba code I am using is this:

```
Set objCollection = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("select")
    'Debug.Print objCollection.Length

    i = 1
    While i < objCollection.Length        'Loop to locate and change the fields with proper data using the "select" tags
        Debug.Print objCollection(i).Value
        If objCollection(i).Name = "entNo" Then
            If ecode <> "" Then
            Debug.Print objCollection(i).Value
                objCollection(i).Value = ecode
            End If

        ElseIf objCollection(i).Name = "curStatus" Then
            objCollection(i).Value = "Open"

        ElseIf objCollection(i).Name = "opStatus" Then
            objCollection(i).Value = "All"


        End If
            i = i + 1
    Wend
```

I can't give more as this is for work. I have exhausted google searches.
One other thing that is strange is that it will work when I single step. It just will not work otherwise. 
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am unable to get the currently selected value.

Comment: If these select elements are somehow dependent (changing one changes the options available in the next) then you need to wait for the next one to populate, which is why it works when stepping through but not if you run the whole thing straight through.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the timing issue for now, your code would be easier as:

```
If ecode <> "" Then ie.document.getElementById("entNo").Value = ecode
ie.document.getElementById("currStatus").Value = "Open"
ie.document.getElementById("opStatus").Value = "All"
```

Since your select elements seem to have id attributes.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for answering. This is much cleaner than what I did.

Comment: I found out that there was something wierd going on with my system. I rebooted and the problem went away. Strange however I closed all appications and tried again but it eventually came down to a reboot. Next time I will just reboot my system before posting.